# Kibana Fatal Error (Server is not ready yet)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

```
retries=0,throttledUntil=0s,bulk_failures=[],search_failures=[]]", "cluster.uuid":   "5FrxkY3GRbGzR2nSuEaxow", "node.id": "kHGHvefFTViG8CdPdF5pxw"  }
kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-05-28T09:15:07+00:00","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":7,"message":"[.kibana_task_manager]  UPDATE_TARGET_MAPPINGS_WAIT_FOR_TASK -> DONE"}
kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-05-28T09:15:07+00:00","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":7,"message":"[.kibana_task_manager] Migration completed after 8648ms"}
kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-05-28T09:15:28+00:00","tags":["warning","plugins","licensing"],"pid":7,"message":"License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch due to Error: Cluster client cannot be used after it has been closed. error"}
 kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-05-28T09:15:37+00:00","tags":["warning","plugins-system"],"pid":7,"message":"\"eventLog\" plugin didn't stop in 30sec., move on to the next."}
 kibana           | 
 kibana           |  FATAL  Error: Unable to complete saved object migrations for the [.kibana] index. RequestAbortedError: The content length (823769731) is bigger than the maximum allowed string (536870888)
 kibana           | 
 kibana exited with code 1
```

I've obtained this error after creating through Vega-lite a number of visualization. How I manage to solve?
If you need I can post all the informations

Answer (score 2):

**After analyzing different response on the web I manage to solve:**

**1 step:**

```
 `http://localhost:9200/.kibana/_search?q=type:dashboard&size=100`
```

**2 step:**

```
`curl -X DELETE "localhost:5601/api/saved_objects/kibanaSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON.index/index-pattern/e68f45b0-ab73-11eb-a01c-8590ef1580f4/" -H 'kbn-xsrf: true'
#(Respectly <name>/<type>/<id>)
`
```

Before doing it I'll do the instruction of this [link](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/95321) to be sure that everything work correctly
In practice the problem is refereed to the fact we've too much saved object over the information in the space. There're different way for solving them in case I've deleted all but you can increase also the space. The other suggestion is to avoid partions